# Java Eclipse TestMaxOfDigits

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to write a program that reads an integer number and shows the user the Max digits of that number. What is the problem with my code ?

I have tried some codes here but eclipse doesn't allow !
what is the correct form ? How should I change it to correct form ?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TestMaxDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n;
        long max = 0;   
            if(n%10>max){
                    max = n%10 ;
        System.out.println("max ="+max) ;


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem in more detail and what errors you are getting

Comment: You are not using `input`. The default value of `long` is 0, so you always test `0%10>max`.

Comment: eclipse doesn't allow What ? Please be more specific and state the errors clearly

Answer (score 0):

You should use `hasNextInt()` and `nextInt()` (or `hasNextLong()` and `nextLong()` ) method from `Scanner` class to read integer number form user input.

Try with this code:

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    while( input.hasNextInt() )
    {
        int n = input.nextInt();
        long max = 0;
        if( n % 10 > max )
        {
            max = n % 10;
            System.out.println( "max =" + max );

        }
    }
}
```

You should describe more what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because logically your code is buggy..

```
public class TestMaxDigits {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        long n;// you never read any input form the keyboard
        long max = 0;   
            if(n%10>max){//this check once for the condition and if found true
            //then assign the value to max in next step.
                    max = n%10 ;
        System.out.println("max ="+max) ;
//but since number may have more than one digit which you never checked in your logic 

        }

    }

}
```

Here is one Way to do it

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input number");
          int input=keyboard.nextInt();
          keyboard.close();
          int max=0;
          if(input>=0){
              while(input!=0){
                  if(max<input%10)
                      max=input%10;
                    input=input/10;
              }
          }else{
              System.out.println("Invalid Input");
          }

           System.out.println(max);

        }
    }
```